# Why would an android user report "Force quits every time I load"?

Tags: android

I'm trying to guess why a user would report "Force quits every time I load"

The problem does not occur for all users, especially not me.

The system constructs a database when it first loads. I suspect that user's phone does not have enough memory.

Questions:
 How can I verify that the system has enough memory to store a small database?
 What else might cause a user's particular system to force quit on startup?

Wrong answers or things I've tried thus far:

- The user's hardware is probably different than mine
- The user's software and available memory is likely different as well
- The data is already loading in its own thread, with a progress dialog showing

Answer (score 1):

Add some smarts to your app to [send you stack traces when the app crashes in the field](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/11/16/diagnosing-sporadic-errors/). That'll narrow down the specific problem and can help you tailor your efforts to clear it up.

Comment: I started a new question to discuss various techniques for this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809586/how-do-i-show-a-dialog-after-the-thread-has-encountered-an-uncaught-exception

Answer (score 0):

Sounds quite odd, does a freshly booted phone give the same error?
Also ask the user to check available storage, might be out if space.

Answer (score 0):

If the UI thread gets frozen for a period of time, then it will show that dialog. Try running the task in the background using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Edit: I'm assuming it's [this](http://code.google.com/android/images/anr.png) error message.

Comment: Good time. However, the data is already loading in another thread