# How do I show a dialog after the Thread has encountered an uncaught exception?

Tags: android, exception

I want to detect when an `uncaught exception` has happened in my Android app.

Once detected, I want to display a confirmation dialog

How do I get this confirmation dialog to display? When I tried various techniques, the UI is unresponsive and appears to be frozen.

My code responds to this:

```
new CatchAllExceptionHandler(this) is my custom handler
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CatchAllExceptionHandler(this));
```

I have tried these two implementations of `CatchAllExceptionHandler`:

1. Display an Alert dialog
2. Start an activity that then displays an alert dialog after onCreate

Both these methods failed.

So my question is: How to I get the confirmation dialog to properly display?

Comment: If you put some code into the handler that writes to your log file, do you see the output there?

Comment: Check out my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73122395/9133569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be attempting to do your UI operations on a non-UI thread. Use any of the available techniques (`Handler`, `Handler#post`, `View#post`, `Activity#runOnUiThread`, `AsyncTask#onPostExecute`) to arrange for your UI work to be done on the UI thread.