# Code execution after System.exit() in android

Tags: java, android, jvm-hotspot

There is a question [how to implement uncaughtException android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943288/how-to-implement-uncaughtexception-android) and best rated answer has code

```
System.exit(2);
defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
```

Is this really correct and this code should be executed?
I've tested this on `HotSpot` and `Dalvik`, and looks like it is not really working.
In witch environment does it works?

Answer (score 0):

`System.exit()` should *never* be called on an `Android app`. This won't close your application cleanly and it's a discouraged way of closing your app.

That said, the code probably tries to represent that the statement is not executed instantly, but it takes a time to close the app. Meanwhile, it might go on running code that's above from that line. It's a similar behavior as when you use `finish()` on an `Activity`. You can place code below of that line and it will be run as well.