# notification for crashed app in android

Tags: android, notifications

I created an app and I want it to be on all the time. I use it on a tablet in a room. So, I was wondering if there is any chance that the app sends me a notification if it crashed or is turned off?

Thanks!

Comment: If you implement some form of crash reporting it can. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8943671/794088

Answer (score 0):

onPause() is called when you exit the application but don't close it, and onDestroy() is called when you close the application. If you want to do something when either of these two methods is called, override them in your activity and add the notification call in there.

Comment: the "crash" is pretty important word in OP's question you apparently missed.

Comment: That's true, but onPause and onDestroy gave me a pretty good hint for a solution thank you!