# Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler with multiple threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception

Our Android application uses several threads.

- The usual UI thread
- A communication layer ( a sticky service ) running several threads to connect to a socket.
- And few more, to load images, videos...

We currently have just one `UncaughtExceptionHandler` defined in our `Application`:

```
public class OurApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    public void onCreate (){
        super.onCreate();

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
                //...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Making some research about this concern we found this ( In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943288/how-to-implement-uncaughtexception-android). ), and we start thinking about **every thread** :

> Basically, you have to implement your own instance of an UncaughtExceptionHandler, then you will have to make sure that for every thread your App runs you call setUncaughtExceptionHandler.

Since we still have some exceptions, basically coming from the sticky service, that are not handled by the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` we are thinking that the handler is not properly set for some threads.

Because the default handler is a static variable of `java.lang.Thread` this not seems to be possible and having just one handler within the `Application` seems to be enough.

Can this be caused for example if the service starts before having defined the handler into the Application?

EDIT:

Our service doesn't run on a separate process :

```
<service
    android:name=".servicios.ServiceBoot"
    android:action="com.aplicaty.soapbox.MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
</service>
```

Any hints or ideas is welcome.

Comment: Just a guess: It could be because your service running in a separate process.

Comment: you can check if the process has the handler or not by calling 
Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler inside the process may be something is wrong with passing the handler to the process.