# Android: Is it possible to stay in "caller" activity after a crash?

Tags: android, exception, crash, android-activity

Imagine this scenario:

```
Activity_1: get Activity_2 started with startActivityForResult;
Activity_2: get Activity_3 started with startActivityForResult;
Activity_3: get some crash in someplace, and all activities will be closed (but not the first one "Ativitity_1").
```

**Is it possible to stay in "caller" activity after a crash caused by an UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION ?**.

I can "do" this by starting next activity just with *startActivity*, not with *startActivityForResult*. But, I need to use *startActivityForResult*.

PS: All uncaught exceptions are been logged and reported to me to get fixed. I just want to get user's life easier, because sometimes he's in "10th deep" activity, and he will lose all his work just because of it.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly the same question its is a bit related. You might consider doing something like this coupled with a data persistance model: [Android: How to auto-restart application after it's been "force closed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681499/android-how-to-auto-restart-application-after-its-been-force-closed)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is possible. You are starting for a result. And result could be not OK.