# android- restart application on force close

Tags: android, forceclose

I have developed an application which uses some external open source projects. For now I have made sure that there is no place where the application would force close. However, I don't want to take chances considering the external opensource apps. I want to make sure that if in case my application force closes, I restart the application from the start.

I searched through the net for a solution and the best I could find was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681499/android-how-to-auto-restart-application-after-its-been-force-closed"here"). However I really couldn't understand how to implement it...

I have seen many applications which open the first screen on force close, so can you give me some some assistance?

Answer (score 2):

The Link you posted is the way to do it. Best will be if you add an Android [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) if not already present. Register an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) Inside Your Applications `onCreate` Method just like this:

```
//Inside your ApplicationClass
public void onCreate(){
    Log.v("MyApplication", "onCreate triggered")
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
         public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex){
             Log.v("MyApplication", "onUncaughtException triggered. Error:")
             ex.printStackTrace()
             //restart your app here like this
             Intent i = new Intent(this, TheClassYouWannaStart.class);
             getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you verified that Apllications.onCreate is run? Put a Log inside like in my updated answer, and check it inside DDMS

Comment: @vivek Are you actually placing this into an application class or an Activity? This won't work in an Activity.

Comment: i have this main page and 6 icons in a grid view... where each icon leads to a different activity.... so i want to check at the main page for exception

Comment: @vivek as AedonEtlira stated: THIS will not work. I made clear that you have to put this inside an Android APPLICATION. Check initial Answer for a link how to invent an Application... Its easy

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you mean service. If you had an application that always made itself present, I would hate you. But for a service, just start it with the [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) flag.

Example

```
public MyAmazingService extends Service {
    @Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // Doing some amazing stuff
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess he just wants to keep his Activity alive when it was closed by an Exception... You're right, if there is a bug inside his first Activity, which could cause an "infinite loop"

Comment: @RafaelT That would be a better assumption than mine. Good call sir.

Comment: no its not services i'm talkin bout.... In terms of unexpected force close i want to close the application and restart it.

Comment: @vivek Then go with RafaelT's answer. However, I **STRONGLY** disagree with that design choice. You are making a decision that should be left up to the user [to reopen the app].