# android reset Heap via restart app?

Tags: android, heap-memory

Due to the "out of memory" issue, is it possible to reset the HEAP via restart app?

Below is the code I found from "stackoverflow" to restart app. But from Eclipse DDMS, the Heap did not reset.

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Thanks...

Comment: why not releasing the objects you allocated and run gc ?

Comment: Actually, it's the google map v1, just can not release it at all. I have tried the way "https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2181" mentioned but from DDMS, even the "MapActivty" is "onDestroy", the heap still not released. By now, I plan to kill the process and restart it again.

Answer (score 0):

> Due to the "out of memory" issue, is it possible to reset the HEAP via restart app?

Eventually, Android will terminate your process, after it moves to the background for a while. The new process will start with a fresh heap.

> Below is the code I found from "stackoverflow" to restart app. But from Eclipse DDMS, the Heap did not reset.

That is because you are still working with the same process.

Comment: See, then is it possible to kill process (int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);) then restart it again. Thanks.

Comment: OK, finally I know how to do that....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681499/android-how-to-auto-restart-application-after-its-been-force-closed