# How disable alert box that appears ,while app crashes in Android

Tags: java, android, restart

I want to handle the crashes smoothly ,for that i am restarting the app for every uncaught exceptions but there is always alert box is there "unfortunately ,xyz has stopped working"
code that i am using to handle uncaught exceptions :

```
intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplication().getBaseContext(), 0,
                new Intent(getIntent()), getIntent().getFlags());

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread,
                    Throwable paramThrowable) {
                Log.e("Alert", "Lets See if it Works !!!");
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, intent);
                System.exit(0);

            }
```

Comment: post your code first.

Comment: you can use "acra" lib for that, it gives user defined message when app crashes and you will get mail of that crash also.

Comment: @Ravi i am having ACRA as well as Crashlytics enabled into my app , but crashlytics it self is fine to report the crash ,i just want the app to be restarted smoothly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           @Override
           public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread,
                           Throwable paramThrowable) {
                   Log.e("Alert", "Restarting app !!!");
                   Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPac
           //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTI
           startActivity(intent);
           System.exit(2);
           }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get "unfortunately ,xyz has stopped working" , always put some breakpoints and DEBUG your code properly.Check your LOGCAT, you will land up finding the problems you are facing when your app crashes. 
Thanks!

Comment: :- It is just in case my app crashes ,it should automatically restart and i want to disable the alert box which comes before app gets restarted

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, i too say that the alert box is done by the system. To be more clear, do you still want to restart activity after it crashes? I have one link regarding the same for you. Hope it works!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681499/android-how-to-auto-restart-application-after-its-been-force-closed

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldHandler =
            Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(
                    Thread paramThread,
                    Throwable paramThrowable
                ) {
                    //Do your own error handling here

                    if (oldHandler != null)
                        oldHandler.uncaughtException(
                            paramThread,
                            paramThrowable
                        ); //Delegates to Android's error handling
                    else
                        System.exit(2); //Prevents the service/app from freezing
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The alert is done by the system, there isn't much you can do about it.

You should just catch an Exception when it is thrown and then let the flow of your app continue accordingly. Restarting your app every time an Exception occurs is anything but smooth.

Comment: ...i also dont want to see that alert box "unfortuantely your app stopped working "

Comment: Well that appears because you don't catch your exceptions properly. Find out where the exceptions are thrown and catch them. Then your app won't crash and the alert box will not be shown.

Comment: This isn't the case for me. I have a kiosk-based rooted device and I need to suppress the message during an APK update. Do you have any pointers to suppress / change the system dialog?