# App auto-restart after FC opens wrong page

Tags: android, android-intent

I followed the most up-voted answer in [Android: How to auto-restart application after it's been "force closed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681499/android-how-to-auto-restart-application-after-its-been-force-closed), and then it works. But when I restart the app running in the background from the desktop icon, the wrong page is opened.

E.g., there's Page A and Page B (A is the 1st one). I open page B after the restarted app after FC, then press <kbd>Home</kbd>. When I start the app from desktop icon, page A is opened. It should be page B. If I open the app from recent tasks, page B is opened. Any advance?

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/how-to-avoid-force-close-error-in-android/) tutorial in my own app.
it kind of uses the same logic as the solution you mentioned but when the force close is caught it will let you open whatever activity you want.

This might be a solution for you since you're specificly saying which activity(page) should be opened.

Hope this helps you out.