# Retain Android Application info after crash

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-applicationinfo

I created a custom application class to keep global informations of my app.

I need to get those informations back after my application restarts from a crash. I don't need to store those informations in disk because is just info from the user current session, but if the app crashed, I should start exactly where the user was before the crash.

I thought in two ways to solve my problem:
1-Track the variables changes and always persist it in the SharedPreferences
2-Always save then in the activity saveInstance and retain then from the savedInstanceBundle

The problem with the solution 1 is an overhead in every change. The problem with solution 2 is that I need to serialize every info.

Do you guys know any other way to solve that problem? I only need to store when the app crashs and load back after starting from a crash. Just in those two scenarios.

Comment: why not just figure out why your app crashes and to something about it instead?

Comment: @e4c5 can you figure EVERY possible situation when your app crashes? Probably not, neither me, so a strategy to recover from any crash is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using the following code to track whenever my app crashes, so i can show a better crash screen to the user, and it also allows me to send information about the crash to my server for later debugging.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        //Get information and save the information 
    }
});
```

But just as a warning, you need to set this in **every** Activity / Service you create for it to be 100% effective.

Personally i have 1 base class for all my Activities, and 1 for all my Services, and then those classes implement the UncaughtExceptionHandler, so that can save ALOT of headeche and code copy-paste.

Comment: If you need to restart your application after the crash, here is a good way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681499/android-how-to-auto-restart-application-after-its-been-force-closed