# Is it possible to prevent or restart the main thread when uncaught exception is thrown

Tags: android, uncaughtexceptionhandler, android-thread

I currently have an app which launches a different Activity if the user has crashed multiple times. However, the app can still crash in this alternate activity due to background services / push services.

Is there a way to prevent the main thread from dying and still retain its message queue. I am using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` and swallowing the exception but seems like the thread still freezes or terminates. I tried `thread.start()` but then all the UI events that were posted to the MessageQueue no longer work (the view is frozen)

Comment: No, fix your code

Comment: Yes, fix your code

Comment: Try placing the entire code inside a try block. But I warn you, it is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Thread.start() is enough in this case. If I understood the problem you cannot handle uncaught exceptions anymore after uncaught exception handler. I think the best way is to start your "different Activity" in another process. [Here is explained how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2903866/1540563).

I've copied some sources from that answer. You first prepare pending intent.

```
intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(/*Applcation context*/, 0,
        /*Intent to 'different activity'*/, /*flags*/);
```

Then in uncaught exception handler you set up alarm manager for let's say 2 sec.

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, intent);
System.exit(2);
```