# How to create service/broadcastreceiver which never force stop with task manager

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver, device-admin

I have an application in which i am taking `device administrator` and that application continuously connect to server to send phone data.

But this background service is stopped after some days and also stopped when anybody kill with task manager !

Even `FCM` receiver is stopped with task manager !

So is there any way that i can service for my app like `whatsapp , fb and other social app` . These app never killed with task manager and if it was killed then it will restart automatically.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: i sthink it's right solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681499/android-how-to-auto-restart-application-after-its-been-force-closed